# MIPS errors with %hi and %lo

Tags: mips

```
lui     $v0,%hi(length)
lw      $v1,%lo(length)($v0)
li      $v0,3                        # 0x3
bne     $v0,$zero,1f
div     $zero,$v1,$v0
break   7
mfhi    $v0
mflo    $v0
sw      $v0,28($fp)
lw      $a1,28($fp)
lui     $v0,%hi(game_over)
addiu   $a0,$v0,%lo(game_over)
jal     printf
nop
```

When I try running this for my MIPS code, it comes up with this error:

Your program produced these errors:
spim: (parser) Unknown character on line 180 of file measurement.s
lui     $v0,%hi(length)

spim: (parser) syntax error on line 181 of file measurement.s
Instruction references undefined symbol at 0x00400038
[0x00400038]  0x0c000000  jal 0x00000000 [init_measure]     ; 159: jal     init_measure

Do I need to substitute %hi and $lo for something else in the code?

***EDIT*** For the following code:

```
sw      $v0,16($fp)
lui     $a0,%hi(grid)
lw      $v1,12($fp)
nop
move    $v0,$v1
sll     $v0,$v0,4
subu    $v0,$v0,$v1
addiu   $v1,$a0,%lo(grid)
addu    $v1,$v0,$v1
lw      $v0,16($fp)
```

And

```
lui     $v0,%hi(column)
lb      $v0,%lo(column)($v0)
nop

sw      $v0,12($fp)
lui     $v0,%hi(column)
addiu   $v1,$v0,%lo(column)
lw      $v0,8($fp)
nop

addiu   $v1,$v0,-1
lui     $v0,%hi(growth)
sw      $v1,%lo(growth)($v0)
b       true
nop
```

Will I be substituting %hi and % lo it in a similar manner or differently?

Answer (score 1):

Those seem to be operators not supported by spim. `%LO(label)` should give you the lowest half of the address of label, and `%HI(label)` the upper half.

You can substitute these two instructions:

```
lui     $v0,%hi(length)
lw      $v1,%lo(length)($v0)
```

with this:

```
la     $v0,length
lw     $v1,0($v0)
```

So we use la pseudoinstruction to load the whole address of the label onto a register (in the example `$v0`) then you directly load its memory contents using `0` as the `lw` offset. Note that `la` pseudoinstruction would use 2 instructions for an arbitrary label address (and leave `$at` with the upper half address).
Also note that in your code `$v0` would still hold the upper half of the label address whereas in the second snippet it will contain the whole address.

Similarily, instead of

```
lui     $v0,%hi(game_over)
addiu   $a0,$v0,%lo(game_over)
```

you can just issue:

```
la $a0, game_over
```

In this case, your code would end with `$a0` having the address of *game_over* label (as in the second snippet), and `$v0` holding the lower half of that address. `la` pseudoinstruction will leave the upper half of the label on `$at`

Comment: Thanks! Would you also be able to see the edit I made to my post just for further clarification?

Comment: @jelica you can do it in the same way as in this answer

Comment: so would lui $v0,%hi(column) / lb $v0,%lo(column)($v0) be la $v0, column / lb $v0, 0($v0)? Sorry just wanted to make sure

Comment: also for the first code in the edited section, it shouldn't matter there is other functions of code between lui 
 $a0,%hi(grid) and addiu $v1,$a0,%lo(grid)?

Comment: Yes, it would be as you wrote. The "state" of the cpu is maintained in its registers, so there is no problem having other instructions interleaved as long as they don't change the value of the register used to load the address.