# Substitution for %hi and %lo in MIPS

Tags: mips, spim

```
lui     $a0,%hi(grid)
lw      $v1,24($fp)
nop   
move    $v0,$v1
sll     $v0,$v0,4
subu    $v0,$v0,$v1
addiu   $v1,$a0,%lo(grid)
addu    $v1,$v0,$v1
lw      $v0,28($fp)
nop
addu    $2,$3,$2
li      $3,3                        # 0x3
sb      $3,0($2)  

lui     $v0,%hi(rows)
lb      $v0,%lo(rows)($v0)
nop

sw      $v0,32($fp)
```

and

```
lui     $v0,%hi(rows)
lb      $v0,%lo(rows)($v0)
nop

sw      $v0,32($fp)
```

Also error for this code:

```
bne     $v0,$zero,1f
```

spim: (parser) syntax error on line 183 of file cubic.s
bne     $v0,$zero,1f

What can I do to modify the %hi and %lo in my first code, and could someone please explain the spim error. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MIPS errors with %hi and %lo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68318576/mips-errors-with-hi-and-lo)

Comment: oh yes thank you. Could you also help explain the spim error at the end with bne     $v0,$zero,1f

Comment: What do you mean by `1f`?

Comment: `1f` most likely refers to an anonymous label named `1` (where the `f` denotes that it's a forward jump, i.e. the label is located somewhere _after_ the jump instruction). Just give the label a proper name if SPIM doesn't support that feature.